# ASP.NEt Sidebar styles keeps refreshing when onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

This is my code in the sidebar

```
<div class="sidebar w3-collapse" id="showside">
    <div class="sidebarbg">
    <center>
        <img id="image" class="w3-round w3-margin-right" src="/images/logo.png" style="width: 50%;">
        
    </center>

    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i><span>Ticket</span></a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EmailView"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i><span>Emails</span></a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action=""><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i><span>Checklist</span></a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action=""><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span>Mobile Users</span></a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span>About</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent the styles refresh onclick

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap everything you dont want refreshed in UpdatePanel

[UpdatePanel Class From Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8)